GlimpseOfLean: Irrelevance of 'rfl' tactic as last step
I'm going through the exercises in Glimpse of Lean, from Patrick Massot, as my first serious attempt to learn about proof assistants, as suggested in Andrej Bauer's course.
Bauer repeatedly emphasizes that a proof assistant like Lean aims at capturing Math the way it's actually done -my wording.
If that's the case, then there is a couple of things that I find odd in those exercises.
In exercise 3 ("ForAll") the author defines the predicate even_fun that states the condition f(-x)=f(x) for a real function on the reals.
Then an example of a proof is shown for even_fun (f+g), where g is of the same type as f.  Skipping some rewrites that proof goes as:
(f+g)(-x) = f(-x)+g(-x) := by rfl
         ...
        _ = f x + g x   := by rw [some hypothesis]
        _ = (f+g) x     := by rfl

It turns out that Lean does not require that last rfl step for building a valid proof.
If a student would hand over this proof w/o that last step I would take some points off that answer: syntactically that's not the right target point. Am I being too old-school?
I can understand that , while (1) adding it improves readability for humans, (2) even without that last rfl Lean is still capable of correctly building the right target type, and thus conclude the proof. I just don't quite see why (2) works?
I guess I mean that for me the proof is incomplete if not including the last step, yet Lean accepts it as a valid proof. So why not "stopping" two steps earlier and call it proven? Specially if "[Lean] is inserting it at every step" as @Trevor seems to suggest in the comments.
But removing the last two steps shown would have Lean claim the goal still active. Hence my question (2): if I don't need to reach the exact syntactic form that I set out to prove, what defines a valid target form?
It feels as if there would be a lot of background results all reachable through 'rfl' that one could use when convenient...if we know them! And in this case, I'm not certain (A) where the last by rfl comes from (where was it defined that (f+g)x=fx+gx??) and (B) when can I assume Lean "knows it (the proof/tactic)"?
Elaborating further on Trevor's comment on "inserting by rfl reasoning at each and every step" is also confusing, I would say even wrong: If I got it right, rfl is an element, aka proof, of type Id_A(lhs,rhs), for whatever type A containing elements lhs and rhs. As such rfl is a formulation of a judgmental identity between lhs and rhs, which is what I'd call "identical by definition".
But, despite all the steps of the proof in that exercise relaying on an = sign, I don't think we can take them all as meaning a judgmental identity, otherwise it would be a moot point asking for a proof. So I guess I can reformulate my question as "when does Lean automatically insert "by rfl"? Uhm...I think Pratrick's file hints at an answer: when it's the last step and only then...
If that's the case, this would be a pure design decision that in my view is a bit unfortunate: I'd prioritize readability over conciseness when writing a proof.

I'm having a bit of trouble finding all your questions in there. I think whatever Andrej said, he was referring more to the high-level design of Lean like (1) using the axiom of choice freely, (2) building general areas of math like Banach spaces, topological spaces, and algebra to prove results instead of rushing to prove a specific result, and (3) covering a large amount of undergraduate and graduate math so much of the needed background is already in Lean. I don't think he was referring to such low-level details. At this level, yes, theorem provers will look different from current math.

He does hint at least to that idea, or I understood it as such, in his (Brauer's) videos -hard rn to pinpoint exactly which/when, maybe the one on Structure & Classes. I understand, though, that a PA as Lean come with some design contraints, so I can accept this would mostly show at a rather high-level. In any case, I still miss the intuition/motivation for why that last 'rfl' tactic is not needed.

You can imagine Lean automatically inserting by rfl reasoning at each and every step, so manually placing that is only for clarity and is never required. But with that said I also don't quite see what exactly the question is. By "why (2) works", do you mean the technical machinery that allows Lean to decide the last two expressions are equal, or the design decision to allow this happen implicitly, or something else?

@Trebor I edited my question concentrating on that point and elaborating it a bit further. To answer your last question: "all of the above options" :-) would help me get a better understanding of this. As mentioned earlier, in my world it's not obvious nor very orthodox that  one can skip that last step. It feels like the usual textbook claiming "it's trivial to proof relation X" or  "it's left as an exercise to the reader to (complete the) proof X": often that's but a poisoned gift far from trivial for the reader.

I didn't expect "the rest is trivial, hence we skip it" as a valid step in a PA.

If I am reading @Trebor correctly, this is not about "the last step", it happens "at each and every step": which makes it at least uniform behaviour, though I too would be curious to know if that's because applying rfl (unification?) comes (almost?) for free, otherwise why Lean does that.

Contrary to usual maths, Lean's theory distinguishes between propositional equality (=) and a judgemental equality (for which there is no internalized symbol). rfl turns a definitional equality into a propositional equality. The difference between the two is that, intuitively, a judgemental equality is "trivial" because Lean can decide it, whereas a propositional equality is something you have to provide a proof for. The reason rfl : (f+g)(x) = f(x) + g(x) is probably because this is the definition of + for functions.


I just don't quite see why (2) works? [...] If I don't need to reach the exact syntactic form that I set out to prove, what defines a valid target form?

There are a set of rigid rules stating what kinds of expressions are definitionally equal. These rules are relatively well studied by logicians, and we have algorithms determining whether expressions are equal in this sense. In the underlying type theory of Lean, definitionally equal expressions are indistinguishable from each other, and you can replace one with the other whenever you want, and still get a valid proof. These rules are a part of the type theory, and if you feel really unsatisfied with them, you can consider switching to a different proof assailant with different rules.
For instance, the entire calc block you wrote is an expression of type (f + g) (- x) = f x + g x, and Lean is expecting an expression of type (f + g) (- x) = (f + g) x. Therefore it runs the aforementioned algorithm, which gave the green light, so it allowed the proof. If you further remove one step in the calc block, then you have constructed an expression of type(f + g) (- x) = f x + g (- x). The algorithm rejected this type as being different from the expected type.
However, definitionally equal terms will not be always treated as the same when checking proofs. Apart from performance, a major reason is that it is impossible for some tactics, like rw, for example, to treat definitionally equal expressions as the same while fulfilling their functions. But this is ok and does not contradict my claim that they are indistinguishable, since tactics are not expressions and not part of the formal language in Lean, but rather little programs that perform operation on expressions to construct other expressions. So as long as the final product of tactics are type checked and valid, all is well. (Indeed, some tactics will generate invalid proofs, but they will be caught by Lean.) It is also desirable for some tactics to infer information from the way you write expressions.

If I got it right, rfl is an element, aka proof, of type Id_A(lhs,rhs), for whatever type A containing elements lhs and rhs.

This is not quite correct. In the code by rfl, rfl is not an element but a tactic that attempts to use a bunch of reflexivity-like theorems to construct the proof. This behavior is determined by whoever wrote this tactic, and you can understand exactly how it works by, well, reading the code for the tactic.

Where was it defined that (f+g)x=fx+gx??

The equality (f + g) x = f x + g x holds by definition, because it is defined this way in Mathlib. And your exercises depend on Mathlib because developing the entire real analysis from scratch just for you to write a couple of exercises is not very practical. As a rough simplified explanation of where exactly it is defined in Mathlib, the path is a little bit winding.  We told Lean that if there is an addition defined on X, then there is also an addition defined on Y -> X, in Mathlib.Algebra.Group.Pi, and the addition operation is defined by add f g x = add' (f x) (g x), where add' is the addition operation defined on X. If you prefer to know all the definitions in a tutorial, you can try the natural number game instead.

When can I assume Lean "knows it (the proof/tactic)"?

What Lean "knows" depends on what you tell it, of course! People have written very sophisticated tactics that knows a lot about continuity, or polynomial algebra, etc. It is up to them to document the abilities of each tactic. In a tutorial though, you generally won't be told the precise purview of each tactic since that usually overwhelms the learner. But when you are writing serious code in Lean, and find a tactic's description confusing, you should reach out to suggest better documentation!

This would be a pure design decision that in my view is a bit unfortunate: I'd prioritize readability over conciseness when writing a proof.

I don't quite understand this, since it is not banning you from writing more detailed proof. You can always self-impose additional best practices on your code instead. Some people prefer concise proofs, and engage in a game called "proof golfing" that attempts to reduce the length as much as possible. (In Mathlib though, this is done with moderation since extreme proof golfing produces unmaintainable proofs.) I don't see why you should rob the option of writing short proofs from these people.

Thanks for the detailed answer. I appreciate all the pointers. You reminded me that the Lean plugin for VS allows for checking, e.g., the definition -it's still too cryptic for me but I get your point. So, if I would set out to formalize a given Math proof or topic, it would be useful to get acquainted with some of those definitional identities relevant to the topic. Maybe even some implementation details of some tactics.

As for the last comment, I would still disagree on the example of proof golfing. Proving something like A --> B as in calc is like unboxing that arrow and substitute it by a path of other "known" arrows leading from A to B. I would hardly call "shortening a proof" when skipping just the last step, but rather when building a new path with, e.g., less intermediate steps. So, in my view, dropping the last step doesn't add anything but subtracts readability. That said, this could be a matter of scale: irrelevant gain in one isolated proof, but maybe substantial code reduction/perf in Lean.

In any case, I accept the design choices and that last point is not a road blocker at all -as you said I can always add the last step. It's also not meant as a criticism, which would be pointless given my limited knowledge. I'm just trying to get a better "intuition" on how Lean works.

@MASL A calc block may appear in any place in a proof. It's true that if a proof is simply a single calc block, it makes sense to require the end points to exactly match. But adding one specific rule for this special case feels unnecessary.
